# Syntax highlighting colors have suddenly lowered in contrast (VSCode)

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, syntax, brightness, contrast

My syntax highlighting colors suddenly look like this:

[image]

It looks as if the contrast or brightness has been lowered, or that it has been grayed out.

I can still use everything normally.

My colors used to look like this:

[image]

My setup:

- VSCode 1.75.1
- Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome)
- One Dark Pro theme (but I have it with every theme)
- Every file gives the same issue, including files in Home directory (to make sure it's not write permissions)

Does anybody know what could be causing and how I could fix this?

Comment: [edit] to provide the settings.json file for a [mre]. Remove anything from the settings.json file that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue. If an empty settings.json file reproduces the issue, say so.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I used to have the Adobe "Source Code Variable" configured as a custom font on Windows, and synced my settings to Ubuntu.

I didn't have the font installed but installed it a bit ago.

After changing to another font it is normal again. Seems like this specific font makes it look low in contrast.

Setting variable: `editor.fontFamily`

Comment: I figured out the cause and updated my answer.